# Heroku: Your account has reached its free tier limit

Tags: heroku

Regarding my dynos expiration, currently using the free tier. I got an email asking me to verify credit card for getting additional dynos for the app to keep running I can't understand any of that because I don't have any credit card type of cards with me since I have only a debit card how do I keep running my app in Heroku by adding additional dynos to it.

Now the error message in the title prevents me from deploying my app and it says it will go to sleep. Google search didn't return a thing. If I have reached the deployment limit how do I free up my concurrent build space?

How do I claim free dynos for re-deploying it without any interruption and without any verification? Thanks

Comment: Heroku has some explanation about free dynos here -> https://www.heroku.com/free. That is basically 550hours (1000 for verified users) per months. In case if you have used them already - you might need to upgrade to paid account. I am not sure what do you mean by "claim free dynos" - those are available by default, and if they are used - then you need to upgrade your account

Comment: Hey thanks, @kurunve that really helped me, and thanks for clarifying my doubt. I mean "claim free dynos" I thought there will be another way of getting free dynos but yes I got that I can only do upgrading it. also, I would like to know that just a "verified credit card" would mean that will they charge my "free type dyno" account in anyway for getting extra dynos, Thanks again.

Comment: Free accounts on Heroku do not get to scale an app to multiple dynos at all.  Verifying gets you more _dyno hours_ that all your apps consume. If you want to scale an app to more dynos, you have to pay for them.

Comment: So simply adding my credit card will apply to charges that are charged for dynos automatically right if so, how much will it charge for dynos? @DavidReed

Answer (score 1):

Unverified Heroku accounts don't get enough hours to run 24/7. You can use these free dynos to model an app, but this is really a "testing level" service. You should leave your dyno running only when you are testing your code in a live scenario. You cannot use this dyno for production-level services, as there simply isn't enough time.

Note that the documentation says that you need to add a "credit card", but this simply means any card that is supported by the credit card network (e.g. Visa or MasterCard); it can be a debit card if that's all you have. This card will never be charged unless you decide to subscribe to a larger plan. Once you add the card, your monthly limit will go from 550 hours a month to 1,000 hours a month, enough to run one dyno 24/7.

To be clear, simply adding your card will just about double your free dyno hours, and you won't be charged anything. I would personally recommend upgrading to the Hobby tier if you plan on leaving the server on for production purposes. For less than $10 a month, your dynos will no longer sleep, you get more process types, and SSL support for custom domains. That's not a bad deal if you can afford it.

Comment: I got that. Thanks for making it clear @sfdcfox

Comment: You said that I would not be charged while on free dyno option, but after being authenticated with a credit card, I was charged USD.96 on heroku. What exactly does this mean? Why am I getting charged when I use the free dyno type? Will I be charged every month .96$ to run my free dynos?

Comment: @TharunP I believe that's just a validation charge; it should be refunded after some time. The system does this to make sure you haven't entered bogus information.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks again.